# pyparse: How to handle "{ foo bar \n }" formatted stream?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm hoping someone can point out a method to get pyparse to handle the following stream of data:

```
"text { \n line1 line1\n line2 line2\n \n }"
```

where the information between the braces is just a blob of strings for further parsing later.  The best I've been able to accomplish is to use skipTo with a failOn attribute.

```
line = SkipTo(LineEnd(), failOn=(LineStart()+LineEnd())|'}') + LineEnd().suppress() 
nxos_clause = "with" + output_file + "{"  + OneOrMore(line.setDebug()) + "}"
```

Debug shows

```
Match {SkipTo:(LineEnd) Suppress:(LineEnd)} at loc 76(4,1)
Exception raised:Found expression {{LineStart LineEnd} | "}"} (at char 94), (line:4, col:19)
(1, 'failed parse:', 'Expected "}" (at char 77), (line:4, col:2)')
```

The output I am looking for would be

```
"{", "line1 line1", "line2 line2", "}"
```

I know this is dead simple to do manually.  I am looking to build a more complex grammar once I get the simple stuff working...

Answer (score 1):

If newlines are significant, you'll need to remove them from the pyparsing set of default whitespace characters.

```
from pyparsing import *
ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(' ')
```

To suppress empty lines, define an expression that matches empty lines, and match and suppress them, before testing for the expression that matches lines that may have content:

```
test = "text { \n line1 line1\n line2 line2\n \n }"
NL = LineEnd().suppress()

LBRACE,RBRACE = map(Literal, "{}")
emptyLine = Suppress(Empty() + NL)
line = SkipTo(NL) + NL
nxos_clause = "text" + LBRACE + OneOrMore(~RBRACE + (emptyLine | line)) + RBRACE
```

Also, note that we had to lookahead inside the `OneOrMore` so as not to process a closing right brace as a valid non-empty line.

Now parse the whole input line:

```
print nxos_clause.parseString(test)
```

Gives:

```
['text', '{', 'line1 line1', 'line2 line2', '}']
```